# Ubuntu One Contacts Sync Error

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, evolution, sync, contacts

I have synced my contacts with Ubuntu One, however, an error occurred, and I have instead of 300 contacts over 1700 contacts and all are messed up.

How can I delete all contacts, and restart the sync process? I tried deleting the contacts via Evolution, but I cannot see any of these 1700 contacts.

Comment: I have the same problem, can someone please provide an answer?

Comment: you both have iPhones?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentMyContactsInEvolutionSyncing

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.